# Tweepy Streaming filter: Why is filter not finding search terms?

Tags: python-3.x, streaming, tweepy

For search, I used Tweepy Streaming filter to track multiple search terms to filter. Streaming code ran ok for 5 hours today during business hours and generated 80MB file of results. I loaded R 80MB file; created R dataframe, then issued grepl("yield") to search for a term inside the 80MB dataframe (streamed file). I issued grepl() for all columns with a search term: "yield"; but zero (0) data frame with 0 columns and 193510 rows. I also tried R dplyr select(contains). Zero results found from tweepy filter.

```
agfarm[,grepl("yield", colnames(agfarm$Value3))] #I tried all columns
agfarm %>% select(contains('yield'))
```

The tweepy filter result file did not appear to find & deliver even a single search term successfully. Are search terms like "nutrient yield" OR "managing crops" OR "food yield" invalid terms? Or is tweepy filter not finding such terms? Does tweepy only work with hashtags: @, # ?

```
my_stream_listener = PrintingStreamListener()
my_stream = tweepy.Stream(auth = api.auth, listener=my_stream_listener)

searchTermsFilter = '"soil yield" OR "nutrient yield" OR "managing crops" OR "food yield" OR "nutrient uptake" OR' \
          '"high yielding crop" OR "fertilizer" OR "soil health" OR "crop yield" OR "acre yield" OR' \
        '"nutrient management" OR "imbalance soil" OR "increase yield" OR "micronutrient" OR' \
        '"sustainability" OR "corn yield" OR "farmers management practices"'

my_stream.filter(track=searchTermsFilter)
```

Comment: Found the answer:

Comment: URL encoding::: 'soil+yield+OR+nutrient+yield+OR+managing+crops+OR+manage-crop+OR+food+yield+OR+nutrient+uptake+OR+nutrient+management'